# how to get any number in specific number of digits

Tags: javascript

Is there not a regular way to output a two digit number from an any number in javascript. I was looking a way to do this for long time. There are lots of manual ways. I wonder about, if javascript does have a regular method to do this.

Expected result

```
1 -> 01
10 -> 10
```

Comment: what's the logic of this 1->01 and 10->01 ,please explain what exactly you are looking for

Comment: 10 -> 01. I don't understand.

Comment: you can get `01` string not a integer

Comment: I think you want to pad numbers with zeroes. You should add this in your question if that is your requirement because currently it's not very clear what you want.

Comment: @PranavCBalan edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method to do that.

```js
console.log(
  ('0' + 1).slice(-2), 
  ('0' + 10).slice(-2)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

using a padding function

```
function zeroPad(num, places) {
        var zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
        return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + num;
}

console.log(zeroPad(12, 3)); //012
console.log(zeroPad(1, 3));  //002
```

returns a **string** type result